# jQuery dynamic Forms remove last label

Tags: jquery, forms, document

I just started learning JS and jQuery and have a question. I want to make a dynamic form which can be complex with more then one Selector. The problem is when I open Option1 and then press the other selector with option6 and 7 it disappears but I want it to be visible. I know the problem is the  $('label').hide(); but I'm so bad at jQuery and Jscript that I don't know how to make this work. I would appreciate any help with this.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('label').hide();
    $('#sel').change(function() {

        var val = $(this).val();

        $('label').hide();

        switch (val){
            case 'option1':
                $('#label1').show();
                break;
            case 'option2':
                $('#label2').show();
                break;
            case 'option3':
                $('#label3').show();
                break;
            case 'option4':
                $('#label4').show();
                break;
            case 'option5':
                $('#label5').show();
                break;

        }
    });

    $('#sel2').change(function() {

        var val = $(this).val();

        $('label').hide();

        switch (val){
            case 'option6':
                $('#label6').show();
                break;
            case 'option7':
                $('#label7').show();
                break;        
        }
    });


    $("input")
        .focus(function () {
            $(this).next("span").fadeIn(1000);
        })
        .blur(function () {
             $(this).next("span").fadeOut(1000);
        });
});
</script>


<style>
label {
    display:block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<form>
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="">- select -</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="option5">Other</option>
    </select>

    <label id="label1">
        <select id="sel2">
            <option value="">- select -</option>
            <option value="option6">Option 6</option>
            <option value="option7">Option 7</option>
        </select>
    </label>

    <label id="label2" for="option2">Text box label 2
        <input type="text" id="option2" />
    </label>
    <label id="label3" for="option3">Text box label 3
        <input type="text" id="option3" />
    </label>
    <label id="label4" for="option4">Text box label 4
        <input type="text" id="option4" />
    </label>
    <label id="label5" for="option5">Other
        <input type="text" id="option5" />
    </label>

    <label id="label6" for="option6">Text box label 6
        <input type="text" id="option6" />
    </label>
    <label id="label7" for="option8">Text box label 7
        <input type="text" id="option7" />
    </label>


</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call #sel2, you keep hiding 'label' every time (which includes itself). I would change it to:

```
$('#sel2').change(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();

    $('#label6').hide();
    $('#label7').hide();

    switch (val){
        case 'option6':
            $('#label6').show();
            break;
        case 'option7':
            $('#label7').show();
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `slice()` method try the following:

```
$('#sel').change(function() {
    var val = this.value.slice(-1); // 1,2,3..
    $('label').slice(0, 4).hide();
    $('#label'+val).show()
});
```

Comment: Ok but I realize I have another problem now, when Option2 should display for example 2 text fields or more form elements how can I do that then ?

Comment: @mat0r you can use `slice` method, like `slice(5,6)` please check the jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: @mat0r you're welcome, you can also use classes for multiple elements and then use the `slice` method, like `.labels` this way you have better control on elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this with just one change function

```
$('#sel,#sel2').change(function() {
    var $selIndex = $('#sel > option:selected').index(); // <-- store index of first select
    var val = $(this).val().replace('option', ''); // <-- remove options from id
    var $label = $('#label' + val); // <-- use number from options to get correct label
    $('label').not($label).hide(); // <-- hide all labels but current selected
    $('#label1').toggle($selIndex == 1); // <-- show if first select = option1
    $label.show(); // <-- show current selected 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wirey00/FqX8k/